# Función se llama a si misma muchas veces *Problema de exceso de llamadas*

Tags: funcion

Creé una función que genera 5 números aleatorios, pero esto me genera un problema de excesos de llamadas. ¿Alguien me podría decir como optimizar este código?

```javascript
async getPostsRandom(state){  
      // Creacion de 5 numeros aleatorios
      console.log('ejecutando')
      let posts = state.posts;
      let numMax = posts.length;
      let numbersRandom = [];
      let postsRandom = [];
      const random = (numMax)=>{
          let numRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * (numMax)));
          if(numbersRandom.includes(numRandom)){
              random(numMax);
          }else{
              numbersRandom.push(numRandom);
              // guardo la publicacion con el indice aleatorio
              // postsRandom.push(posts[numRandom]);
              if(numbersRandom.length === 5){ 
                return;
              }else{
                random(numMax); 
              }
          }  
          
      }
      await random(numMax);
      //prueba 
      
      for(let i = 0; i < numbersRandom.length; i++){
        console.log(numbersRandom[i],i)
      }
      return numbersRandom;
    }
```

En la consola se puede ver el error siguiente:

```
index.js?68eb:19 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

No comprendo porque el ciclo `for` se ejecuta 4 veces si la recursividad la hago antes.

Comment: ¿Y debe ser recursiva?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos errores en tu código (o al menos dos oportunidades de mejora):

### No hay razón ninguna para que la función sea recursiva

Según creo yo, tu algoritmo trata de lo siguiente:

- Generar un número al azar entre 0 y `maxNum`
- Mirar si ya estaba en la lista. Si no estaba, se mete y se retorna cuando la lista tenga 5 elementos.
- Si ya estaba, probar a generar otro hasta que salga uno que no esté.

Este último paso lo implementas llamando de nuevo a `random()`, que es la propia función que estás definiendo. Es por tanto una llamada recursiva. Si tienes "mala suerte" y los números que sacas están siempre en la lista, acabarás agotando la pila de llamadas.

No hay razón ninguna para que la llamada sea recursiva. Simplemente puedes "insistir" con un bucle `while` que cree números con `random.Math()`. Es decir, en vez de esto:

```js
let numRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * (numMax)));
if(numbersRandom.includes(numRandom)){
   random(numMax);
}else{
   ...
}
```

esto otro:

```
let numRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * (numMax)));
while (numbersRandom.includes(numRandom)){
     numRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * (numMax)));
}
...
```

### Mejor aún

Aún tras eliminar la llamada recursiva innecesaria, el método no es muy eficiente, pues a medida que el array se va llenando de números diferentes, cada vez será más difícil encontrar números que no estén ya en el array. El bucle `while` de la solución anterior se ejecutará más y más veces conforme el array se vaya llenando.

Una solución a este problema es cambiar el enfoque. Lo que puedes hacer es:

- Crear un array con todos los números entre 0 y `maxNum`
- "Barajarlos" (desordenar el array)
- Retornar los 5 primeros una vez barajado.

La implementación de esta idea podría ser por ejemplo así:

```
const random = (numMax)=>{
   let numeros = [];
   // Crear array ordenado
   for (let i = 0; i< numMax; i++) {
      numeros.push(i)
   }
   // Barajar el array
   numeros = numeros.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());
   // Retornar los 5 primeros elementos
   return numeros.slice(0,5);
}
```

Podrías por ejemplo llamarlo así:

```
let numMax = 8;
let numbersRandom = random(numMax);
      
for(let i = 0; i < numbersRandom.length; i++){
    console.log(numbersRandom[i],i)
}
```

Resultado:

```
6, 0
3, 1
2, 2
5, 3
1, 4
```

Aquí lo tienes en forma de snippet ejecutable para que lo pruebes:

```js
const random = (numMax)=>{
    let numeros = [];
    for (let i = 0; i< numMax; i++) {
      numeros.push(i)
    }
    numeros = numeros.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());
    return numeros.slice(0,5);
}

//prueba 
numMax = 8;
numbersRandom = random(numMax);
for(let i = 0; i < numbersRandom.length; i++){
  console.log(numbersRandom[i],i)
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudaste mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Significa que en algún lugar de su código, está llamando a una función que a su vez llama a otra función y así sucesivamente, hasta que alcanza el límite de la pila de llamadas.

Esto casi siempre se debe a una función recursiva con un caso base que no se cumple.

Considera este código...

```
(function a() {
    a();
})();
```

Para solucionarlo, asegúrese de que su función recursiva tenga un caso base que se pueda cumplir...